# Peace Lily leaves turning yellow and brown

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, leaves, peace-lily

After 2 years of health, some of the leaves on my peace lily started turning yellow towards brown on the edges. I water it with the same frequency, have a constant temperature and have it outside of direct sunlight. Can I save it and is there a specific reason why this started happening?

[image: Leaves with brown edges]

Answer (score 1):

I used to maintain tropical plants commercially and this was the only problem that spathiphyllums had aside from flopping when they were dry.

If you look on the margins of the dead areas you can see the typical symptoms of a fungus/virus/bacteria infection which are the dead or necrotic area is surrounded by a yellow ring where the problem is active. The symptoms go though a growth/pause/growth phase.

Commercially there was no solution and we just trimmed the leaves until it was time for it to go.

For a homeowner I can suggest these solutions:

- repot with sterile potting mix or even potting mix with some sterilized top soil
- add a capillary wick and a reservoir so the plant is never wet but has access to water
- move to a  higher light area and be prepared to supply water more often

My theory is that a healthy plant can out grow most infections so if you change the circumstances it has a chance.

Comment: @kevinski, many thanks, that all makes sense and it is very useful, I will repot it tomorrow and monitor it, will update this post in a few months as I believe it can outgrow it as well, it is such a resistant plant.